# Remove portion of plot that lies outside of circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written a python script that produces vector field plots of the electric and magnetic field vectors for EM waves in various modes of propagation in a cylindrical waveguide. I have used `streamplot` to produce the vector field plots. This question would be asked much more easily if I were able to post an image of my plot but I am currently unable to since my reputation is currently below 10.

Although the mathematics of the script is formulated in cylindrical coordinates, due to the difficulty of using `streamplot` on a polar plot, I have plotted the cross sectional (electric) field vectors on a standard square grid using: 
`pyplot.streamplot(X, Y, UE, VE, linewidth=lwE, density=6,color='r')`. If you're interested, lwE is defined elsewhere in my script and simply scales the line widths according to the magnitude of the vector at that point.

Anyway, my problem is that, naturally, due to being plotted on a square grid, the field vectors extend slightly outside the boundary of the cross section of the cylinder in the corners of the plot. I just want the plot to display the vector fields *inside* the cylinder, not outside. This problem can be solved by using a polar plot, but I cannot get `streamplot` to work on a polar plot. In short - matplotlib returns a square plot; I want to 'cut out' the parts of the plot that lie outside of the circular cross section of my cylinder.

I would like to know the best way to 'cut out' these unwanted portions of the plot. My first thought was to plot a 'circ' function (circular aperture type function available in some software packages) that is only nonzero inside of a certain radius; sadly, there does not appear to be such a function available. I have tried overlaying transparent circles onto my plot, and whilst they do clearly highlight the region of interest, the 'unwanted' regions outside the circle are still present; I want these portions completely removed.

I can set the (x,y) limits of the plot using `axes.set_xlim([-a,a])` and
`axes.set_ylim([-a,a])` ; what would be useful is a polar version of this (say `axes.set_rlim([0,a]`). This is obviously trivial if one is able to use a polar plot in the first place, but does such a limit command exist if one is using Cartesian axes?

Answer (score 1):

You can [plot streamlines in polar coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601865/matplotlib-how-to-plot-streamlines-in-polar-coordinates/). You can also clip your streamlines in Cartesian coordinates like in [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQdlY.png):

```python
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

x = numpy.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(x, x)
s, t, u, v = -y, x, x, y

# patch defining where streamlines would show
clip_patch = PathPatch(
  Path([[1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, 0]]),
  edgecolor='none', facecolor='none')
pyplot.gca().add_patch(clip_patch) # important!

# unclipped streamlines
pyplot.streamplot(x, y, s, t)

# clipped streamlines
plot = pyplot.streamplot(x, y, u, v)
plot.lines.set_clip_path(clip_patch)
for arrow_patch in pyplot.gca().patches[-len(plot.arrows.get_paths()):]:
  arrow_patch.set_clip_path(clip_patch)

# matplotlib version
from matplotlib.patheffects import withStroke
white_border = withStroke(
  linewidth=0.5*matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'], foreground='white')
pyplot.annotate(matplotlib.__version__, (0, 0), (-0.9, 0.9), 'data', 'data',
  ha='left', va='top', path_effects=[white_border])

pyplot.xlim(-1, 1)
pyplot.ylim(-1, 1)
pyplot.savefig('stream.png') # or .pdf, but apparently not .svg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a clip path. Matplotib's documentation has a nice example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo_clip_path.html

Comment: Actually; I have just realised that whilst this works for *images* (such as my intensity plot, this is done using `imshow`), the streamplot (which is laid over the top of the image) still extends outside of the clipping area. So I'm only halfway there; I am able to successfully clip images, but not normal plots. That link does not appear to discuss such a case.

Comment: All matplotlib artists have a set_clip_path() method. Use this on every plot object you want to be clipped.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I'm using `axes.set_clip_path(patch)` with `patch = patches.Circle((0, 0), radius=a, transform=axes.transData` (this is what I interpret from what you have written, with a being the radius of the circle), but the stream plots still extend outside of the desired area. Using `clip_path=patch, clip_on=True` as an `imshow` kwarg works perfectly fine; it's just the streamplots that are not clipping correctly.